# Add classes to all items which don't include more ul elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have a problem. Please see the part of my code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 7</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">Test 8</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test 12</a></li>  
    </ul>  
  </li>  
</ul>
```

I want to add classes to all items which don't include more ul elements - please see what I want to achieve:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Test 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 7</a></li>  
  <li><a href="#">Test 8</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 10</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="link">Test 12</a></li>  
    </ul>  
  </li>  
</ul>
```

I want to use jquery. Many thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) with the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

```
$("li").not("li:has(ul)")
       .children("a")
       .addClass("link");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4zsq/

---

Or given that the `a` elements to be targeted seem always to be an only child, you can use the [`only-child`](http://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/) selector.

```
$("li > a:only-child").addClass("link");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4zsq/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li > a').filter(function() {
  return !$(this).siblings('ul').length;
}).addClass('link');
```

**edit**

Just noticed in your question that you wanted the nested list anchors to have the `link` class as well, something like this should work:-

```
$('li > a').addClass('link').filter(function() {
  return $(this).siblings('ul').length;
}).removeClass('link');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").each(function(){
    if($(this).children('ul').length == 0)
        $(this).addClass('link');
});
```